# Help with “web3 not defined”

Tags: web3js, ether, javascript, dapps

I am cloning a tutorial https://github.com/techaddict0x/liquidityminer
And when I run the debug console I get the error “web3 is not defined”
The code is the exact same, looked all over the internet and I can’t seem to find the right answer , any help would be greatly appreciated- thanks

Comment: Did you actually download the necessary dependencies ?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, I believe so you mean npm install ? 
I did npm I web3

Comment: Is there any chance could try cloning the GitHub for me and seeing if you have the same error, I really only know solidity and contracts etc

Comment: If you’re into cryptocurrency, I can send you some tokens in my upcoming project for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed the dependencies, then you need to create a web3 instance in order to use its functionalities . In this code i have created a web3 instance of Polygon Mumbai Testnet.
`const web3 = new Web3("https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com");`